# How to not import imported submodules in a Python module?

Tags: python, import, module, visibility

In my Python modules I often use sub-modules such as `datetime`. The issue is that these modules become accessible from outside:

```
# module foo
import datetime

def foosay(a):
    print "Foo say: %s" % a
```

From IPython:

```
import foo
foo.datetime.datetime.now()
```

I would like to know how to properly hide the sub-modules that are the internal business of `foo`.

I naively thought about `import datetime as _datetime` or even `import datetime as __datetime`, but this is not very pleasant solution. I've also read about `__all__`, but it only concerns what is imported using `from foo import *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the import datetime within the function that uses it in module foo:

```
def foodate():
    import datetime
    print datetime.datetime.now()

def foosay(a):
    print "Foo say: %s" % a
```

Now importing foo will not import datetime.

**EDIT:** You can also reduce the memory footprint by not importing the whole datetime module, only the methods/functions you need:

```
from datetime.datetime import now
```

Comment: Is it bad habit and more resources consuming than the standard solution?

Comment: Yes because every time you call foodate() it will process the import statement.

Comment: Well, it is not a suitable solution, though.

Comment: If you want to reduce the memory footprint, you can import more specifically. from datetime.datetime import now